# How to see details of an error in Task Scheduler with 0XFFFFFFF code

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, tasks

I am running a Task in Windows Server 16 but the Status always shows 0XFFFFFFF Is there a way to see more descrption of the error. Will you get this if the Process which it is trying to start is already running. Here are the thing it tries to execute:

In Program: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Metrohm\tiamo\bin\BackupServer.exe"
Start in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Metrohm\tiamo\bin\

Task History only shows "Task completed" Operation code(2)

Comment: See if this helps:   ......   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7985a545-7a89-4991-ab61-367f8488f739/scheduled-task-error-0xffffffff?forum=Forefrontclientgeneral#:~:text=The%20error%20code%200xFFFFFFFF%20indicates,it%20means%20nothing%20to%20us.&text=Hope%20this%20helps.&text=Please%20remember%20to%20click%20%E2%80%9CMark,not%20actually%20answer%20your%20question.

Answer (score 0):

If the task is an app that writes to an Event Log, look there. It might be easier to examine all Event Logs at once with a third-party tool, such as Nirsoft's excellent (and free) [FullEventLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html), which has search capability. Using that tool, you can restrict events viewed by time-span, from just before the task should have triggered to a perhaps 15 minutes after.
[image: FullEventLogView Advanced Features]